# Lack of consistency between snpEff annotation vcf file and the summary statitics generated

Tags: grep, vcf-variant-call-format

I have computed the SNP annotation using snpEff using this following command line:
j`ava -jar  /apps/x86_64/snpeff/snpEff/snpEff.jar aa_stecla ./vcf/stec_stec_pool.filter.vcf > stec_stec_pool.filter_ann.vcf`.
This generates an annotation file **stec_stec_pool.filter_ann.vcf** and a statistic summary file **snpEff_summary.html**.  One of the table of the summary statistic file shows the number of LOW, HIGH and MODERATE impact variants as follow:
[image]

However, when I grep the those strings from my annotation file, I get different results:

*grep -c HIGH stec_stec_pool.filter_ann.vcf*

129

*grep -c LOW  stec_stec_pool.filter_ann.vcf*

22930

*grep -c MODERATE  stec_stec_pool.filter_ann.vcf*

10355

Do you have any idea why my numbers from 'grep' are lower than what I see in my in my summary file? which one to report?